# Which sentence is correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Could you advise - which is correct.

1.) We are pleased to offer you services of one of our developers.

Or

2.) We are pleased to offer you services of one of our developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"one of our"  denotes more than one - so the correct word is "developers"

unless you mean to say 
"We are pleased to offer you services of our developer"

Comment: I have many developers but i want to offer service of one developer. In this case, i guess the first sentence is correct. Right?

Comment: @user3286962 of course, 1st one is correct.

Comment: @user3286962 - the 1st one is correct because although you have many developers, you're only offering "services of one of [them]".

Answer (score 0):

*We are pleased to offer you **the** services of one of our developer**s***.

Comment: I appreciate @Colin fine answer more than com nut, he corrected the sentence!